# How to send parameters in Angularjs $state.go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am developing AngularJS application. I am trying to send values in `$state.go` to different states. I am trying as below.

This is my state:

```
$stateProvider
.state('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    url: '/RegistrationOTPVerification',
    templateUrl: 'Registration/RegistrationOTP.html',
    controller: 'RegistrationOTPVerification'
});
```

I am trying as below.

```
var customerid = response.data.ID;
var OTP = response.data.OTP;
$state.go('Registration.OTPVerification', customerid,OTP);
```

I am trying to receive parameters in below controller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('RegistrationOTPVerification', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, $stateParams) {
        var customerid = $stateParams.customerid;
        var OTP = $stateParams.OTP;
        alert(customerid);
    }]);
})();
```

I am not able to receive parameters. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: in state URL change /RegistrationOTPVerification/:customerid/:otp and in $state.go('Registration.OTPVerification',{customerid:1,otp:2314}) then it will work. Need in Url and pass in redirection

Comment: @VinodLouis OTP and such sensitive information should probably not be part of URL params?

Comment: @tanmay Im not supporting for OTP to pass via URL i was just demostrating how to pass path params

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have those as `params` in order to be able to send them through `state`. Like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    url: '/RegistrationOTPVerification',
    params: {
        customerid: null,
        OTP: null
    },
    templateUrl: 'Registration/RegistrationOTP.html',
    controller: 'RegistrationOTPVerification'
});
```

Now, you can use `$state.go` like following:

```
$state.go('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    customerid: 123,
    OTP: 2323
});
```

Finally, you can access them way you are using `$stateParams.customerid` and `$stateParams.OTP` but make sure you have `$stateParams` injected just like you have `$state` and `$translate` injected.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting below error. Failed to instantiate module RoslpApp due to:
Error: Invalid params in state 'Registration.OTPVerification'

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole according to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1949#issuecomment-101260542), that message comes from versions of ui-router `0.2.10` and earlier and those versions don't support passing objects as parameters. So you need to update your version of `ui-router`

Comment: I added  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>. I removed error.but now i am getting error as Cannot read property 'customerid' of undefined

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole as I have mentioned in answer, you need to inject `$stateParams` just like `$state` and `$translate` in your controller where you have `$stateParams.customerid`

Comment: I am using the above solution and its not working.  Its routing to the right controller/page but no parameters are being passed.  Does `params` have be defined at the root level of the `.state(..)` ? I have my `params` under a `views` and its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$state.go` as this:

```
$state.go('Registration.OTPVerification',
    {
     customerid: response.data.ID,
     OTP: response.data.OTP
    });
```

Also you need to define the url parameters in the `$stateProvider.state` as:

```
$stateProvider
 .state('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    url: '/RegistrationOTPVerification',
    params: {
        customerid: '',
        OTP: ''
    },
    templateUrl: 'Registration/RegistrationOTP.html',
    controller: 'RegistrationOTPVerification'
});
```

Here's the updated controller to get the params:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('RegistrationOTPVerification', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, $stateParams) {
        var customerid = $stateParams.customerid;
        var OTP = $stateParams.OTP;
        alert(customerid);
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: You can also set the initial values of the params to `null`.

Comment: Thank you. When i changed my route i got following error. Unknown provider: $stateParams

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole you should add it to the controller you are trying to get the params

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole I've updated the answer to fix provider error too

Comment: @Mert i am getting below error. Failed to instantiate module RoslpApp due to:
Error: Invalid params in state 'Registration.OTPVerification'

Answer (score 0):

Link - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Syntax - go(to, params, options)
params - A map of the parameters that will be sent to the state, will populate $stateParams

```
$stateProvider.state('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    url: '/RegistrationOTPVerification/:data',
    templateUrl: 'Registration/RegistrationOTP.html',
    controller: 'RegistrationOTPVerification'
});

$state.go('Registration.OTPVerification', response);

(function () {
   angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('RegistrationOTPVerification', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, $stateParams) {
        var customerid = $stateParams.data.ID;
        var OTP = $stateParams.data.OTP;
        alert(customerid);
    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.
   $stateProvider
   .state('Registration.OTPVerification', {
    url: '/RegistrationOTPVerification',
    params: {
          customerid: null,
          OTP:null
          },
   templateUrl: 'Registration/RegistrationOTP.html',
   controller: 'RegistrationOTPVerification'
  })
```

when calling pass parameter like this:

```
 $state.go('Registration.OTPVerification',{customerid: "gfdg",OTP:"4545"});
```

Comment: Thank you. If i put params: {
          customerid: null,
          OTP:null
          }, i am getting error. Do i need to inject anything to work with params?

Comment: no . you can  set initial values as null. Which type of error you are getting??.

Comment: Invalid params in state 'Registration.OTPVerification' I am getting this error

Comment: i am getting below error Failed to instantiate module RoslpApp due to:
Error: Invalid params in state 'Registration.OTPVerification'

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my two cents to this.  There is a gotchya in the above solutions that cause others issues.  I use `views` in my states and was placing the `params` ($stateParams) in the `views` and it wasn't working.  The `params` must exist at the root level of the state controller.  I am not certain if you can pass them listed under the `views`...and if you can how you would go about passing/retrieving the values.

Here is my initial state controller definition:

```
  .state('tab.clubs', {
      cache: true,
      url: '/clubs',
      views: {
        'tab-clubs': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-clubs.html',
          controller: 'ClubCtrl',
          params: {
           'refreshClubs' : 0,
           'pushAction' : 0,
           'pushSub' : null,
           'pushMsg' : null,
           'pushCode' : null
         }
        }
      }
    })
```

Then in controller:

```
var payload = {
   'pushAction' : 1,
   'pushSub' : "blah",
   'pushMsg' : "more blah blah",
   'pushCode' : code
}
$state.go('tab.clubs',payload) ;
```

It would route to the proper controller/page, but no parameters were being passed.  Until I changed the state provider to the following:

```
  .state('tab.clubs', {
      cache: true,
      url: '/clubs',
      params: {
        'refreshClubs' : 0,
        'pushAction' : 0,
        'pushSub' : null,
        'pushMsg' : null,
        'pushCode' : null
      },
      views: {
        'tab-clubs': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-clubs.html',
          controller: 'ClubCtrl'

        }
      }
    })
```